# Any good number theory/algebra problems that can be converted into Geometry questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, number-theory

I was wondering if there are any difficult (difficult for my amateur level is about AIME problems 10+) problems that are initially number theory/algebra problems that are very hard to solve, but then made easy converting them into a geometrical diagram?

Comment: My favorite is the existence/uniqueness of the decomposition of a prime $p$ as the sum of two squares (assuming $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$).  Not sure "easy" is the word I'd use, but it's not too bad.  The argument appears in Hardy and Wright's famous text on Number Theory.  I can dig up a more detailed reference if this example appeals.

Comment: @lulu i was looking more for an AIME problem and less of a proof

Comment: Don't think this is hard enough, and it is a prove problem: show that $$6\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}<\pi$$

Comment: @MarkFischler are you familiar with any aime questions that fit my criteria?

Answer (score 0):

AIME 10+ is not amateur at all. Here's one: Prove that there are infinitely many different values for $(x:y:z)$ where $(x,y,z)$ is a pythagorean triple.

AIME Style: Suppose $z > x,y$. Determine the sum of all possible sums $x+y+z$ where $z < 20$. If it's greater than 999, mod by 1000.